# JavaFX Tableview holding two kinds of objects

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml, classcastexception

I'm currently writing a program with JavaFX and FXML. My current problem is that I have an `FXMLTableView`, which should display traits of two different object-classes, `Stockorder` and `Article`, namely the name, id and price of the article and how many of that article are in stock (which is defined in stockorder). I currently have the following Code:

Stockorder:

```
public class Stockorder {

    private SimpleStringProperty deliveryState;
    private SimpleStringProperty stockOrderId;
    private SimpleStringProperty orderdate;
    private SimpleStringProperty deliverydate;
    private SimpleStringProperty count;
    private SimpleStringProperty itemId;
    private SimpleStringProperty itemName;

    public Stockorder(String deliveryState, String stockOrderId, String orderdate, String deliverydate, String count, String itemId, String itemName) {
        this.deliveryState = new SimpleStringProperty(deliveryState);
        this.stockOrderId = new SimpleStringProperty(stockOrderId);
        this.orderdate = new SimpleStringProperty(orderdate);
        this.deliverydate = new SimpleStringProperty(deliverydate);
        this.count = new SimpleStringProperty(count);
        this.itemId = new SimpleStringProperty(itemId);
        this.itemName = new SimpleStringProperty(itemName);
    }

    public boolean getDeliveryState() {
        return Boolean.valueOf(deliveryState.get());
    }

    public StringProperty getDeliveryStateProperty() {
        return deliveryState;
    }

    public int getStockOrderId() {
        return Integer.parseInt(stockOrderId.get());
    }

    public StringProperty getStockOrderIdProperty() {
        return stockOrderId;
    }

    public String getOrderdate() {
        return orderdate.get();
    }

    public StringProperty getOrderdateProperty() {
        return orderdate;
    }

    public String getDeliverydate() {
        return deliverydate.get();
    }

    public StringProperty getDeliverydateProperty() {
        return deliverydate;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.parseInt(count.get());
    }

    public StringProperty getCountProperty() {
        return count;
    }

    public int getItemId() {
        return Integer.parseInt(itemId.get());
    }

    public StringProperty getItemIdProperty() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty getItemNameProperty() {
        return itemName;
    }
}
```

Article:

```
public class Article {
    private final SimpleStringProperty articleNr;
    private final SimpleStringProperty name;
    private final SimpleStringProperty price;

    public Article(String articleNr, String name, String price) {
        this.articleNr = new SimpleStringProperty(articleNr);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.price = new SimpleStringProperty(price);
    }

    public int getArticleNr() {
        return Integer.parseInt(articleNr.get());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return Double.parseDouble(price.get());
    }

    public StringProperty getArticleNrProperty(){
        return articleNr;
    }

    public StringProperty getNameProperty(){
        return name;
    }

    public StringProperty getPriceProperty(){
        return price;
    }
}
```

EditArticleOverviewControl (FXMLController)

```
public class EditArticlesOverviewController implements Initializable {

    public EditArticlesOverviewController() {
        System.out.println("EditArticleOverviewController started");

    }

    private ApplicationControl applicationControl;
    private EditOrderController editOrderController = new EditOrderController();
    private String stockOrderURL = "stockorders";
    private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    @FXML
    TableView<Article> tableView;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Article, String> articleNrColumn;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Article, String> nameColumn;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Article, String> priceColumn;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Stockorder, String> stockColumn;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Stockorder, String> minStockColumn;

    @FXML
    TableColumn<Stockorder, String> addColumn;

    @FXML
    Button cancelButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        articleNrColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getArticleNrProperty());
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getNameProperty());
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getPriceProperty());
        stockColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getCountProperty());
        minStockColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getDeliveryStateProperty());
        addColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getCountProperty());
    }

    public void setApplicationControl(ApplicationControl applicationControl) {
        this.applicationControl = applicationControl;
    }

    public void setEntriesInTableView(ObservableList articlesList) {
        tableView.setItems(articlesList);
    }

    @FXML
    public void goBack() {
        System.out.println("Kein Artikel bearbeitet");
        Stage stage = (Stage) cancelButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
        //EditOrder wieder starten vom selben Order wie vorher!!
        try {
            applicationControl.openEditOrder(applicationControl.order.getOrderNr());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OrdersOverviewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Now every time I try to run the program, I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: client.Article cannot be cast to client.Stockorder
```

at the line where I set the `cellValueFactory` for `stockOrder`. But I can't understand why, as the column holds `Stockorder` and the `cellValueFactory` uses methods of the `Stockorder` class.

Comment: can you point the line ?

Comment: stockColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getCountProperty());
That one. The fourth 'setCellValueFactory' in the **EditArticlesOverviewController* Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your code,

```
TableColumn<Stockorder, String> stockColumn;
```

It means `stockColumn` will try to get items **as Stockorder**. The S of `TableColumn<S, T>` affects S of [`setCellValueFactory(Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<S,T>,ObservableValue<T>> value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellValueFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) and return type S of [`TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<S,T>::getValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellDataFeatures.html#getValue--).

But actually, items in the `TableView` is not instance of `Stockorder`, so `ClassCastException` is thrown at runtime. All S type of `TableView<S>` and `TableColumn<S,T>` must be same.

In this case, to show them in a `TableView`, there is a need to create a data model class for use it. For example:

```
class RowData {
    private Stockorder stockorder;
    private Article article;
    public RowData(Arthicle article, Stockorder stockorder) {
        this.article = article;
        this.stockorder = stockorder;
    }
    public Stockorder getStockorder(){ return stockorder; }
    public Article getArticle(){ return arthicle; }
}
```

Comment: And then the <S> of the TableView and all TableColumns would be RowData?
And the Method would be  `[...] -> cellData.getValue().getStockorder().getCountProperty());` ?

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot! I'll probably try to just squish two TableViews into the FXML as a first try, as there's a whole lot of other stuff I'd need to change to make that RowData class work, as this class is just a small piece of a bigger project :)